# overlapping shape and character in ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I plot points and text with the same colour, the `a` and the shape overlap in the legend.

Can I tell ggplot not to draw the `a` in the legend? How?

```
M <- data.frame(t=letters[1:16],
            xx=runif(16),
            yy=runif(16),
            g=rep(c("A","B","C","D"),4))
str(M)

ggplot(M,aes(x=xx,y=yy,label=t,colour=g)) + 
       geom_point(shape=3) + 
       geom_text(vjust=0,hjust=0) + 
       scale_colour_discrete()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `show_guide = F` for your `geom_text`:

```
ggplot(M,aes(x=xx,y=yy,label=t,colour=g)) + 
  geom_point(shape=3) + 
  geom_text(vjust=0,hjust=0, show_guide = F) +
  scale_colour_discrete()
```

[image]